# Why can't I change the names of annotation layers in Blender 2.8?

Tags: annotation

When I hover over an annotation layer the tool tip says "Active Layer Index. Double click to rename". However, when I double click, nothing is happening.

Is this a bug?

I use Blender v2.82.6 under Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a workaround:

Hover with the mouse cursor over the annotation layer you want to rename, press `ctrl` and double tap `enter`.

After that I was able to enter a layer name.

Comment: CTRL + Click also works apparently

Comment: This is a bug/oversight and a ticket should be made. Blenders naming convention is f2 or double click.